# Java indexOf for Multiple strings in one pass

Tags: java, indexof

Is there a way I can use indexOf in Java to find the position of multiple strings in a given text in a single parse?

For example,
I want to do an indexOf for "you" and "meeting" in one single parse of the text
"Will you be able to attend the meeting today?"

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: and, what would be the answer in a single parse? would a regex (like "you.*meeting") be good enough, denoting where the expression starts and where it ends

Comment: This question is ambiguous.  Do you want the position of each of the strings (returning a list / array of positions), or the position of the first occurrence of any of the strings?  Also, what constitutes a "pass"?  A pass through the text of a pass through the strings?

Answer (score 3):

As you phrase the question: no.

However you can use a regular expression with matches, string.matches(".*(meeting|today).*"). See the javadoc for the syntax on regular expressions. If you only use letters and number 
you can construct the pattern from the example, but some characters need quoting with a \, which inside a literal like this would become \.

Answer (score 2):

if you're searching for some patterns in your text then use regular expressions. 
In your case, i would write a basic function, if you want to locate some strings in a text given:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    String a = "i have a little dog";
    String [] b = new String [] { "have", "dog" }; 
    locateStrings(a,b);
}

public static int [] locateStrings(String source, String [] str) {
    if (source == null || str == null || str.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int [] result = new int [str.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
        result[i] = source.indexOf(str[i]);
    }
    return result;      
}
```